# ¿Cómo usar Facebook Pixel en un proyecto de Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook

Tengo un código de Facebook Pixel el cual necesito ponerlo en una de las rutas de mi sitio web hecho con Angular 2.

Mi proyecto tiene varias rutas, como:

```
/
/x
/y
/z
```

Mi proyecto es simple, sólo utiliza un módulo y todas las rutas están en el mismo archivo de rutas. Tengo que poner el código de Facebook en la sección `x` la cual manda a llamar a `xComponent`.

El código de mi Facebook Pixel es el siguiente:

```
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
```

Me pregunto si poner ese código dentro de `x.component.html` es la mejor opción.
¿Cómo podría integrar el pixel de facebook?

Answer (score 0):

No se detecta porque el compilador no lo encuentra ya que está definido en index.html (y por tanto fuera de los archivos de typescript que reconoce por el compilador).

Para solucionar esto, agregue una declaración ambiental a los archivos donde usa 'fbq', así:

```
 declare const fbq: any;

   @Component({...})
       export class ComponentUsingFacebookPixel {
       fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration'); 
   }
```

Esto no modifica el 'javascript' que se compila, ni sobrescribe el valor de 'fbq', es una promesa para el compilador para que encuentre un valor con ese nombre disponible en la ejecución.